# moodle no change in status 'in progress'

Tags: moodle

I am facing problem with moodle configurations. I have 2 courses setup and the activity completion set for these courses are 1. manual self comletion and 2. Manual completion by manager.
I have also added required blocks for the same.
I completed the course successfully, marked completed by student as well as manager. In the status block it shows [block image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2MBs.jpg)

Need help to get the status showing complete. I dont know what exactly i am missing.

Answer (score 1):

You should start the [Moodle cron tasks](https://docs.moodle.org/32/en/Cron) in order to update the completion status.
You can manually start the tasks either by running (only if you are an admin) a command from your browser:

```
 http://your.site/admin/cron.php
```

or by running a command line in you system (from a terminal), like:

```
/path/to/your/moodle/installation/admin/cli/cron.php
```

A list of predefined cron tasks of you system can be found under:

```
http://your.site/admin/tool/task/scheduledtasks.php
```

or going under Site administration->Server->Scheduled tasks